# Concatenate different types using ranges-v3

Tags: c++, range-v3

I would like to know if its possible to concatenate two vectors holding different type of objects, such that I can then iterate on the concatenation and call a common interface.

Something like this:

```
    std::vector<A> as;
    as.resize(3);

    std::vector<B> bs;
    bs.resize(4);

    for (const auto &v : ranges::views::concat(as, bs))
    {
        foo(v);
    }
```

You can find a full example here
https://godbolt.org/z/nr5hhWMxj

Answer (score 7):

You can use `views::transform` to convert the elements of both containers to `std::variant` for type erasure.

```
auto to_variant = ranges::views::transform(
                    [](auto x) { return std::variant<A, B>(std::move(x)); });
for (const auto& v : ranges::views::concat(as | to_variant, bs | to_variant)) {
  std::visit([](const auto& v) { foo(v); }, v);
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vWrE7o67M)

Comment: At which point, one wonders whether two separate consecutive loops might not be better. Also, OP didn't say `foo()` should not modify the original. Or that copying is cheap enough / possible.

Comment: I guess it depends how easy is to use two separate loops. If you have 10 type of objects and you need to iterate on all of them in different places, its better to use this kind of tricks. Even more if at some point you may add a new type. Ofc, we could use virtual, but that requires dynamic allocation

Comment: the `auto` in the lambda for transform could be a forwarding reference to avoid copy?

Comment: @jjcasmar What about the point of copies versus references to original?

Comment: If `foo` is already a functor then you can simplify the loop body to `std::visit(foo, v)`

Comment: If you don't want to make a copy and want to modify the original element, you can use `std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<A>, std::reference_wrapper<B>>`. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/o733G5qrf)

Comment: @DeduplicatorI have actually ask about it. Ideally, it should avoid copy and I should be able to call non const methods on the original objects

Comment: Probably better not to actually concatenate at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that is simple:

**What is the common interface?**

If they have a common type, like one is descended from the other, `views::concat()` is intelligent enough to go there, and you still have dynamic dispatch for `virtual` member functions.

If they are both descended from the same base (but neither is the base), you would be able to get the above by using `views::transform()`.

Otherwise, you would need to `views::transform()` them into a proxy-object which can reference either, and dispatches the members you care about appropriately.
While `std::variant` cannot be it, unless you are fine with a copy, `std::variant` storing `std::reference_wrapper`s may work.

```
auto map = ranges::views::transform([](auto& x) {
    return std::variant<std::reference_wrapper<A>, std::reference_wrapper<B>>(std::ref(x)); });
for (const auto& v : ranges::views::concat(as | map, bs | map))
    std::visit([](auto x) {
        auto& v = x.get();
        foo(v);
    }, v);
```

#### Alternative

Use `static_for_each`:

```
template <class F, class T>
constexpr void static_for_each(F&& f, T&& t) {
    std::apply([&](auto&&... x){
        ((f(std::forward<decltype(x)>(x)), void()), ...);
    }, t);
}

static_for_each([&](auto&& c){
    for (auto&& v : c)
        foo(v);
}, std::forward_as_tuple(as, bs));
```

Comment: I wonder what happen with constness in this case. Do I need different `map` transforms to be able to hold a reference wrapper to a const value?

Comment: As in the other example, you would have to adjust for each additional combination of type / cv-qualifier. Anyway, I prefer the alternative.

Comment: I also like better the alternative, as it doesnt involve virtual dispatch as the variant version. I wonder if there is a way to use a static dispatch with the `concat` stuff.